# How can I configure the Jenkins Radiator View to auto-fresh?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

[Radiator View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Radiator+View+Plugin) is very useful to monitor the CI result in public monitor.

While in configuration, there is no parameter for auto-fresh and the time for the refresh, also when it is enabled, it shows in whole browser, no menu or button is available.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is connected with jenkins's "Enable Auto refresh" button, so

1. before coming to this page, "Enable auto refresh" to make it auto-fresh for your browser
2. you can directly add ?auto_refresh=true in this view